# Storing a collection of String into Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, rest

I want to store my String datatypes into a firestore to edit later..
i made a collection of strings for my app

example:

```
String Google :'https://www.google.com/';
String Facebook :'https://www.facebook.com/';
String Reddit :'https://www.youtube.com/';
String ...... :'https://..........';
String ...... :'https://..........';
```

i want to edit these links later..without pushing an app update..someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store these strings in Firebase's Firestore and listen to them on your app or, you can use Firebase's Remote Config.

**FireStore Data:** (One time fetch when the function is called)

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME")
        .document('THE_DOCUMENT_ID')
        .get()
        .then((ds) {
      setState(() {
          googleLink = ds.data["google"];
        });
    });
```

NOTE: It is possible to make the Firestore Data as a continuous stream of data, instead of `.get()` use `.listen()`.